# one doubt on big oh notation

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

I see an example that $f(n)=O(n)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(n)=O(n^2) $ in which $f_i$ is a function from natural to natural number.

> I ran into a challenge, that above notation is differ from the
> following or not? my misunderstanding point is why the above fact is
> false?

[image]

Comment: It's entirely unclear what the $i$ in your $f_i(n)$ is representing. Can you be more specific about your _specific_ question, what statement you think (or have been told) is false?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think it means $n+n+n+...+n$ and differ from the attached figure.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki just say in my note "$f_i$ is a function from natural to natural number.

Comment: If $\{f_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of functiosn such that each $f_i\in O(n)$, then it is in general not the case that the map $n\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^nf_i(n)$ is $O(n^2)$ or any other nice big-oh at all. For what it's worth, we might have $f_i(n)=e^i\cdot n$, for example

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen so there is two differ question, would you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot proves a $\Theta(n)$ function's values from $1$ to $n$ have a $\Theta(n^2)$ sum. The sum of $n$ functions in $O(n)$ being $O(n^2)$ (if that's what you were asking about) requires a different treatment. Indeed, since each of the $f_i(n):=in\in O(n)$ but $\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(n)\sim\tfrac12n^3$, it's not true in general. If however some $f\in O(n)$ upper-bounds all $f_i$, you can use a strategy almost identical to the screenshotted one.

Comment: exactly. excellent. how you can get that sigma result is approximate to $1/2n^3$ this is exaclty my points. so there is two different question. am I right? (attached figure is differ from first statement)

Comment: @LaraKat$$\sum_{i=1}^nin=n\sum_{i=1}^ni=n\tfrac12n(n+1)=\tfrac12n^2(n+1)\sim\tfrac12n^3.$$

Comment: would you please verify me: if $f \in O(n)$ is upper bound for all $f_i$ the screenshot is proof for more general version of first statement (one part of theta proof considered o notation so also proof the first statement) but if all $f_i$ equals to $n$ then first statement is wrong and differ from attached picture. am I underestand completely?

Comment: @LaraKat We need a new proof, but a very similar one. If for some $f\in O(n)$ some $c_1,\,c_2$ satisfy $c_1f(n)\le f_i(n)\le c_2f(n)$ for $n>N$ with $i$-independent $N$,$$c_1nf(n)\le\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(n)\le c_2nf(n)\implies\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(n)\in O(n^2).$$Note if the minimum $N$ for these inequalities are $i$-independent, we again might not get $O(n^2)$. I'll try to suggest an example in a later comment.

Comment: so would you please consider my last comment for two interpretation of the question? (Except proof part)

Answer (score 0):

$\Theta$ is the two sided version of big $O$.  If something is $O(n^2)$ it can be anything smaller, like $n$.  $\Theta$ says it is within a constant factor, so $n=O(n^2)$ but $n \neq \Theta(n^2)$  The statement you quote is true if the leading $f$ is replaced by $f_i$, meaning that each $f_i(n)=O(n)$

Comment: pardon me, statement quote is about first statement or figure?

Comment: my problem is these two fact is the two differ one or the same?

Comment: The first statement in your post.  An alternative way to correct the problem is to make the thing being summed $f(i)$

Comment: If the two are $O$ and $\Theta$, that is exactly what I answered.